# Is this identity true? And how to prove it

Tags: matrices

Let \begin{gather*}
A=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)&-\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)\\
\sin \left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)& \cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)
\end{pmatrix},
\end{gather*} 
where $n$ is an integer with $n\geq 2.$ 
Consider the following expression
\begin{gather*}\tag{$\star$}
I_2+A+A^2+\cdots+A^{n-1}=\begin{pmatrix}
0&0\\0&0
\end{pmatrix}. 
\end{gather*}
Here $I_2$ is the identity matrix of order 2.
I think $(\star)$ is true. But I do not know how to prove it. I have check it by Maple from $n=2$ to $n=20,$ with a definite answer. Is it really true?

Comment: It is very easy to compute all the powers of the matrix using the fact that $\cos^{2}x-\sin^{2}x=\cos(2x)$.

Comment: $A$ is simply the (usual) linear representation of a root of unity in the complex plane.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Thank you.  I've got it. At first glance, I was terrified by the given expression, which I figured out when considering an another problem proving that the sum of vectors from the center of a regular polygon to all vertexes is zero vector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$(I-A)(I+A+A^2+\cdots+A^{n-1})=I-A^n=O.$$
Now prove that $I-A$ is nonsingular to get your identity.

Comment: Actually, it is necessary to show $A^n=I_2$ at first. Based on Kavi Rama Murthy's comment, this is easy.